# Ubuntu 14.04.3 install: grub-efi-amd64-signed failed (Dualboot, Windows, UEFI)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, uefi

I have got a MSI Notebook with 2 SSD and one HDD inside.
I installed Windows on SSD one and Ubuntu on SSD two. The HDD is for some data.
After that, I could not boot Ubuntu - Windows 8.1 started every time. I chanced the boot order or selected Ubuntu manually, but Windows starts ever time.

So I tried to install Ubuntu on the second SSD again, but I got the following error while installing:

```
grub-efi-amd64-signed failed to install into /target/.
Without GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot

[OK]
```

(I uploaded the bug report to Launchpad, too: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/1498049 )

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.3 from an 4GB USB Stick. I put the .iso file with the Windows tool "Rufus" on the USB stick and made it ready for UEFI/GPT.
I also disabled secure boot and fast boot in the UEFI / BIOS.

```
Model: ATA KINGSTON RBU-SNS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size   File system  Name                          Flags
 1      945MB   1079MB  134MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      1079MB  1394MB  315MB  ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 3      1394MB  1498MB  105MB  fat32        EFI system partition          boot
 4      1498MB  128GB   127GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata


Model: ATA KINGSTON RBU-SNS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB   ext2
 2      512MB   40,5GB  40,0GB  ext4
 3      40,5GB  128GB   87,5GB  ext4


Model: ATA ST2000LM003 HN-M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  1984GB  1984GB  ntfs                  msftdata
 2      1984GB  2000GB  16,8GB  linux-swap(v1)
```

*On SSD two (/dev/sdb):*

*1 --> "/boot"*

*2 --> "/"*

*3 --> "/home"*

And the output from *sudo efibootmgr -v*:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0006
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0005,0000,0006
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(3,298800,32000,3648d254-da11-4efb-ab3d-4aa95833ebe1)File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...d................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(3,298800,32000,3648d254-da11-4efb-ab3d-4aa95833ebe1)File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0005* ubuntu    HD(3,298800,32000,3648d254-da11-4efb-ab3d-4aa95833ebe1)File(\EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI)..BO
Boot0006* UEFI:  USB DISK 2.0 PMAP  ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1d,0)USB(0,0)USB(0,0)HD(1,800,7777df,7664c587-000f-4e06-8ecd-089284227db1)..BO
```

*(The ubuntu one is the first instillation, which failed to start.)*

Comment: This user had to go into UEFI and change boot order there, to get it to work. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218742

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried exactly the same, but it did not run :(

Comment: Does Windows boot? And did you change order drives are plugged into SATA ports? efibootmgr says HD(3 which is third drive. But ESP - efi system partition is on first drive? But Ubuntu drive order does not always match UEFI/BIOS drive order.

Comment: Yes, windows boot every time. When I press F11 on boot to show boot menu, I can select "Windows Boot Manager" or "ubuntu" or "ubuntu". If I select "ubuntu", Windows starts. If I select "Windows Boot Manager", Windows starts. If I select the other "ubuntu", Windows starts...

Comment: Well at least your system is consistent. It only likes Windows. We have found many systems that seem to want to only boot Windows. Several of the work arounds. The two that work best are the copy of grub or shim into /EFI/Boot and rename to bootx64.efi to boot a default hard drive entry in UEFI or use rEFInd. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried to make **a1**, but there are some files missing. Here you can see some folders and files from my EFI partition: http://pastebin.com/BNSn9WUp

Comment: Your UEFI entry shows /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi and grubx64.efi?? Did they get erased. Your efi partition also is sda3, not the typical sda1. So you have to use sda3 in the mount command. You can reinstall with Boot-Repair, booted in UEFI mode. You can add it to Ubuntu installer. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Yes, I mounted sda3. How you can see in the pastebin link above, the /EFI/ubuntu folder is empty, so there is no shimx64.efi or grubx64.efi file. How you can see in my main post, grub failed to install while installing ubuntu again: `grub-efi-amd64-signed failed to install into /target/.
Without GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot`

Comment: If you run Boot-Repair to reinstall grub do you get same error? You have to make sure partitions are mounted. Normally desktop installs do not need /boot partition. But LVM with full drive encryption does need a separate /boot.

Comment: You may be seeing filesystem damage caused by the Windows "Fast Startup" option (better called "Fast Filesystem Damage," IMHO). Try disabling it in Windows, as described [here.](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) Note that this feature is *entirely unrelated* to a firmware feature that often has a similar name. It's the *Windows* feature that absolutely *must* be disabled. After you disable this feature, re-install GRUB.

Comment: After disableing fast secure and secure boot, I run the Boot-Repair tool on a Ubuntu live-USB stick. After that, I must edit the boot order in my UEFI. This solved my problem! GRUB is starting every time.

I worked so many hours at this problem! Thanks for helping solving it!

Comment: During the install try putting ~500 MB efi partition.

Answer (score 2):

How you can see in the comments, I solved the problem:
After disableing fast secure and secure boot, I run the [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool on a Ubuntu live-USB stick. After that, I must edit the boot order in my UEFI. This solved my problem! GRUB is starting every time.